# Create binary variables from categorical with sparse matrix

Tags: r, data.table, sparse-matrix

I have this data.table:

```
df <- data.table(u = c(1,2,3,4,5), d = c(1,2,0,1,2), V1 = c(0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2), 
                     pred = c(1,2,0,1,0), sec_pred = c(2,1,0,1,0), ones = rep(1,5))

#   u d  V1 pred sec_pred ones
#1: 1 1 0.3    1        2    1
#2: 2 2 0.2    2        1    1
#3: 3 0 0.2    0        0    1
#4: 4 1 0.1    1        1    1
#5: 5 2 0.2    0        0    1
```

And I want to get matrix like this one:

```
dcast(df, u + d + V1 ~ pred + sec_pred, fill = 0, value.var = 'ones')

#   d  V1 u 0_0 1_1 1_2 2_1
#1: 0 0.2 3   1   0   0   0
#2: 1 0.1 4   0   1   0   0
#3: 1 0.3 1   0   0   1   0
#4: 2 0.2 2   0   0   0   1
#5: 2 0.2 5   1   0   0   0
```

But as I have a very big data.table, I want to create a sparse matrix. But it would be great to create all possible combinations of `pred` and `sec_pred` values, such as 0_0, 0_1, 0_2, 1_0, 1_1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option may be

```
library(Matrix)
v1 <- df[, do.call(paste, c(.SD, list( sep="_"))), .SDcols = 4:5]
j1 <- match(v1, unique(v1))
sM <- sparseMatrix(1:nrow(df), j1, x=1, 
                     dimnames = list(NULL, unique(v1)))
sM
#   5 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#     1_2 2_1 0_0 1_1
#[1,]   1   .   .   .
#[2,]   .   1   .   .
#[3,]   .   .   1   .
#[4,]   .   .   .   1
#[5,]   .   .   1   .
```

If we need to `order`

```
sM[,order(colnames(sM))]
#5 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#     0_0 1_1 1_2 2_1
#[1,]   .   .   1   .
#[2,]   .   .   .   1
#[3,]   1   .   .   . 
#[4,]   .   1   .   .
#[5,]   1   .   .   .
```

Comment: Thanks! if I want all possible combinations, how should I change your code?

Comment: @VitaliyRadchenko  In that case use `combn` on the unique values of the dataset.  With the example you provided, it was not clear.

Comment: @VitaliyRadchenko  Perhaps `df2 <- expand.grid(rep(list(unique(c(df$pred, df$sec_pred))),2))` , `paste` the columns together and check with paste elements from the original dataset.